# Cart page Total amount change observable

Tags: magento2, knockoutjs, shopping-cart

Three statements to explain my question:

Without page load:

- I want to update one value on the same page via ajax request if cart
  total change.
- I want to observe Cart Total changes by increasing/decreasing the
  quantity (by ajax) on cart or in mini cart or by removing the item
  etc.
- On checkout_cart_index How I can call any js function if cart total
  change?

Comment: The first thing that would come to my mind would be the use the  "change" js/jquery event on the html element containing your total and then you can execute whatever you want.

Comment: I want something in proper way like some kind of KO observer or any thing else wrt to frontend which I use related to total price change.